# How to upload file into my server php

Tags: php, html

i'm trying to upload images into my server, but with my code i can't create not even the directory. where is the error? the browser show me in the bottom of the screen a % of upload but at the end of this the images and directory don't exsist.

```
$modello = $_POST["modello"];
  $marca = $_POST["marca"];
  $prezzo_base = $_POST["prezzo_base"];
  $uomo = $_POST["uomo"];
  $donna = $_POST["donna"];
  $bambino = $_POST["bambino"];
  $descrizione = $_POST["descrizione"];

  $img1=($_FILES['foto1']['tmp_name']);
  $img2=($_FILES['foto2']['tmp_name']);
  $img3=($_FILES['foto3']['tmp_name']);
  $img4=($_FILES['foto4']['tmp_name']);
  $img5=($_FILES['foto5']['tmp_name']);
  $img6=($_FILES['foto6']['tmp_name']);

  mkdir("/res/".$newindex ,0777);

  $inviato1=file_exists($img1);
  $inviato2=file_exists($img2);
  $inviato3=file_exists($img3);
  $inviato4=file_exists($img4);
  $inviato5=file_exists($img5);
  $inviato6=file_exists($img6);

  if($inviato1 && $inviato2 && $inviato3 && $inviato4 && $inviato5 && $inviato6){
    move_uploaded_file($img1,"/res/".$newindex."/foto1");
    move_uploaded_file($img2,"/res/".$newindex."/foto2");
    move_uploaded_file($img3,"/res/".$newindex."/foto3");
    move_uploaded_file($img4,"/res/".$newindex."/foto4");
    move_uploaded_file($img5,"/res/".$newindex."/foto5");
    move_uploaded_file($img6,"/res/".$newindex."/foto6");
  }else {

  }

  $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and no idea where/how `$newindex` is assigned as.

Comment: I think it is permissions issues.

Comment: the value of $newindex is assigned and correct

Comment: what kind of permissions?

Comment: and error reporting will tell you about it. did you check? anyway, someone gave you an answer below.

Comment: @Fred the report is this:  mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Unable to access /res/23 . /res/23 is the directory where i would upload the images

Comment: try a  full system path instead of `/folder/`. I.e.: `/var/usr/htdocs/folder/` - or relative path `folder/` or `../folder/` depending on where you're executing from.

Comment: btw, are you on Windows or * NIX?

Comment: @Fred i resolved with folder/  Without the first "/" thank you so much!!

Comment: I posted an answer then to mark it as solved. You're welcome. @Davide

Comment: Now the folder is created but i can't put the file into the new directory. i have this error: Unable to access res/bici 21/foto1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"@Fred i resolved with folder/ Without the first "/" thank you so much!! – Davide"*

Either use a full system path instead of `/folder/`, since that is considered as trying to use a system path syntax.

I.e.: `/var/usr/htdocs/folder/` - **or** a relative path `folder/` or `../folder/` depending on where you're executing from.

The manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php states:

```
<?php
mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0700);
?>
```

and for Windows:

```
<?php
$path = 'd:\path\to\my\file';
mkdir($path, null, true);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to give the file destined a name with an extension of the file type like JPG or PNG.

Here you go, try it and tell me what you think ...

```
<?php

  $modello = $_POST["modello"];
  $marca = $_POST["marca"];
  $prezzo_base = $_POST["prezzo_base"];
  $uomo = $_POST["uomo"];
  $donna = $_POST["donna"];
  $bambino = $_POST["bambino"];
  $descrizione = $_POST["descrizione"];

  $img1=($_FILES['foto1']['tmp_name']);
  $img2=($_FILES['foto2']['tmp_name']);
  $img3=($_FILES['foto3']['tmp_name']);
  $img4=($_FILES['foto4']['tmp_name']);
  $img5=($_FILES['foto5']['tmp_name']);
  $img6=($_FILES['foto6']['tmp_name']);

  $imagename1 = 'image-1.jpg';
  $imagename2 = 'image-2.jpg';
  $imagename3 = 'image-3.jpg';
  $imagename4 = 'image-4.jpg';
  $imagename5 = 'image-5.jpg';
  $imagename6 = 'image-6.jpg';

  mkdir("/res/".$newindex ,0777);

  $inviato1=file_exists($img1);
  $inviato2=file_exists($img2);
  $inviato3=file_exists($img3);
  $inviato4=file_exists($img4);
  $inviato5=file_exists($img5);
  $inviato6=file_exists($img6);

  if($inviato1 && $inviato2 && $inviato3 && $inviato4 && $inviato5 && $inviato6){
    move_uploaded_file($img1,"/res/".$newindex."/foto1/".$imagename1);
    move_uploaded_file($img2,"/res/".$newindex."/foto2/".$imagename2);
    move_uploaded_file($img3,"/res/".$newindex."/foto3/".$imagename3);
    move_uploaded_file($img4,"/res/".$newindex."/foto4/".$imagename4);
    move_uploaded_file($img5,"/res/".$newindex."/foto5/".$imagename5);
    move_uploaded_file($img6,"/res/".$newindex."/foto6/".$imagename6);
  }else {

  }

  $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: i tried to add the file extension but it don't create not even the directory